# Removing everything after a certain character in a string in Tcl

Tags: string, tcl

So, this looks really trivial but I was unable to solve it.

After a regex run in a file line like:

(In this example I'll be looking for /Name: it could be as well for Arch.Type etc...)

> /Name: Plugin     /Version: 1.0   /Arch: Windows 64 Windows 32 Linux Mac      /Summary: asdasdas      /Type: sdfsdf

I've got a string like:

> Plugin   /Version: 1.0   /Arch: Windows 64 Windows 32 Linux Mac      /Summary: asdasdas      /Type: sdfsdf

I need to remove everything from this string that it's after the first "/"  (Thus leaving only "Plugin")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove everything from the first `/` in a string onwards using this:

```tcl
set myVar [regsub {/.*} $myVar ""]
```

```tcl
# Old school Tcl 8.4 and before version (upgrade, man!)
regsub {/.*} $myVar "" myVar
```

It's better to not capture the stuff that you don't want in the first place though.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
regexp {/Name: ([^/]+)} {/Name: Plugin /Version: 1.0 /Arch: Windows 64 Windows 32 Linux Mac /Summary: asdasdas /Type: sdfsdf} all match
puts $match
```

Parenthesized capturing expression that will match any character but slash, one or more times.

Comment: +1 — Not capturing the stuff you don't want in the first place is a _great_ idea, and it's trivial to implement.